# How to record audio on IOS device through website

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webrtc, getusermedia

I seen few working examples with getUserMedia and WebBRTC but didn't find any tutorial how to do it. I want record audio in all devices IOS(MacOS)/Android/Windows and send recorded file to my server.

Comment: This should get you started: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/

Comment: @Rax on localhost not working, should I use in production server with https?

Comment: That's a very broad question. Can you share your code and demonstrate the steps you have performed? Please update the question with details on what you have tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, gUM cannot access microphones or cameras unless the JavaScript program it’s in comes from an https: server. This is a pain in the neck for developers, but necessary to keep cybercreeps from spying on our users.

I use a cheap certificate and put an entry in my /etc/hosts file pointing the hostname on the cert to 127.0.0.1 and ::1. To do this I have to own the domain.

One vendor, namecheap, resells Comodo certificates for us$10. Or you could use the free certs from Lets Encrypt.

If you work for a company, ask your IT hostmaster person for help rigging this. It’s a very common setup needed by almost all front-end devs.